# store Iframe content (PDF) in a variable (blob) in JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, blob

I have an Iframe on a page. This iframe displays a PDF-file. How do I store this PDF in a variable (I guess this variable type is supposed to be blob)? I need to do it in order to works with this PDF further in JS. I tried to get the Iframe by its Id and than get iframe.contenDocument but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What do you mean by work with it? If you need to manipulate the file itself you would need to do an ajax request to the url where the pdf file is in order to get the actual file. You cant manipulate a pdf through DOM api if your were meaning to manipulate it live on the page

Comment: yes, I need to manipulate with the PDF itself. I can't do an ajax request.  So I'm thinking of getting this file thru iframe. Is it possible to get actual pdf from iframe?

Comment: "I can't do an ajax request." why? Where is the pdf stored?